# CRegKeyEx GetValuesCount returns invalid number

Tags: c++, windows, registry, registrykey

I have this code in C++/VS2013/Win7x64, the app is compiled in 64-bit

```
CString strKey=_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\SharedDLLs");
CRegKeyEx   reg;

// Count entries
if (reg.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKey, KEY_ALL_ACCESS) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return;

if (reg.QueryInfo() != ERROR_SUCCESS) return;
dwCountEntries = reg.GetValuesCount();
```

This is the CRegKeyEx class

```
ifndef __REGKEYEX_H__INCLUDED__
#define __REGKEYEX_H__INCLUDED__

#include <atlbase.h>

//
// Enhanced version of ATL's CRegKey class
// After you open/attach the key, you should call QueryInfo in order
// to initialize some members which this class use.
//
class CRegKeyEx : public CRegKey
{
public:

    // Retreives information about the key
    LONG  QueryInfo();

    // Number of subkeys
    DWORD GetSubKeysCount() { return m_cSubKeys; }
    // Number of values
    DWORD GetValuesCount()  { return m_cValues;  }

    // Enumerate values of arbitrary type
    // allocate space in ppBuff (you have to free() it)
    LONG EnumValue(DWORD dwIndex, CString& strName, 
                   LPBYTE* ppBuff, DWORD* pBuffSize, DWORD* pType);
    // Enum value as String
    // *pType will be REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ
    LONG EnumValue(DWORD dwIndex, CString& strName, CString& strValue, DWORD* pType);

    // EnumKey with CString output
    LONG EnumKey(DWORD dwIndex, CString& strName);


protected:
    DWORD m_cSubKeys;
    DWORD m_cMaxSubKeyLen;

    DWORD m_cValues;
    DWORD m_cMaxValueNameLen;
    DWORD m_cMaxValueLen; // this is in bytes (can be any kind of data)
};


// ---- implementation ----

// Retreives information about the key
inline LONG CRegKeyEx::QueryInfo()
{
    LONG ret;
    m_cSubKeys = 0;
    m_cMaxSubKeyLen = 0;
    m_cValues = 0;
    m_cMaxValueNameLen = 0;
    m_cMaxValueLen = 0;
    ret = ::RegQueryInfoKey(m_hKey, 
                NULL, NULL, NULL,
                &m_cSubKeys, &m_cMaxSubKeyLen,
                NULL,
                &m_cValues, &m_cMaxValueNameLen, &m_cMaxValueLen,
                NULL, NULL);

    // include the terminating NULL character(s)
    m_cMaxSubKeyLen++;
    m_cMaxValueNameLen++;

    return ret;
}


// Enumerate values of arbitrary type
// allocate space in ppBuff (you have to free() it)
inline LONG CRegKeyEx::EnumValue(DWORD dwIndex, 
                                 CString& strName, 
                                 LPBYTE* ppBuff, 
                                 DWORD* pBuffSize,
                                 DWORD* pType)
{
    TCHAR  *pName;
    DWORD   cName;
    LPBYTE  pBuff = NULL;
    DWORD   dwBuffSize = 0;
    DWORD   dwType;
    LONG    ret;

    // Allocate space for buffers
    pName = (TCHAR*)malloc(m_cMaxValueNameLen * sizeof(TCHAR));
    cName = m_cMaxValueNameLen;
    if (ppBuff != NULL) // data may not be required
    {
        pBuff = (LPBYTE)malloc(m_cMaxValueLen);
        dwBuffSize = m_cMaxValueLen;
    }

    // Retreive name and data
    ret = ::RegEnumValue(m_hKey, dwIndex, 
                pName, &cName,
                NULL, &dwType,
                pBuff, pBuff ? &dwBuffSize : NULL);

    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        free(pName);
        free(pBuff);
        return ret;
    }

    // Resize the buffers
    pName = (TCHAR*)realloc(pName, (cName + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    if (pBuff)
        pBuff = (LPBYTE)realloc(pBuff, dwBuffSize);

    if (ppBuff)
        *ppBuff = pBuff;
    if (pBuffSize)
        *pBuffSize = dwBuffSize;
    if (pType)
        *pType = dwType;

    strName = pName;
    free(pName);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

// Enum value as String
// *pType will be REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ
inline LONG CRegKeyEx::EnumValue(DWORD dwIndex, 
                                 CString& strName, 
                                 CString& strValue, 
                                 DWORD* pType)
{
    DWORD   dwType;
    LPBYTE  pBuff;
    LONG    ret;

    ret = EnumValue(dwIndex, strName, &pBuff, NULL, &dwType);
    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return ret;

    if (pType)
        *pType = dwType;

    if (dwType == REG_SZ || dwType == REG_EXPAND_SZ)
    {
        strValue = (TCHAR*)pBuff;
        free(pBuff);
    }
    else
    {
        free(pBuff);
        return ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE;
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

// EnumKey with CString output
inline LONG CRegKeyEx::EnumKey(DWORD dwIndex, CString& strName)
{
    TCHAR  *pName;
    DWORD   dwLen;
    LONG    ret;

    // Allocate space for buffers
    dwLen = m_cMaxSubKeyLen;
    pName = (TCHAR*)malloc(dwLen * sizeof(TCHAR));
    memset(pName, 0, dwLen * sizeof(TCHAR));

    ret = CRegKey::EnumKey(dwIndex, pName, &dwLen, NULL);
    strName = pName;
    free(pName);

    return ret;
}

#endif __REGKEYEX_H__INCLUDED__
```

The registry key have 1725 values and GetValuesCount returns only 762 !

Comment: Hmm, strange, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com) doesnt show anything about `CRegKeyEx`.

Comment: hmm, you're right, I am using a custom class, and it's pretty long to post it here. My mistake.

Comment: I have included the custom class in the post

Comment: Some comments: 1) you should always initialize your private members (unless the compiler does that for you implicitly); 2)Why do you request `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` when (for this particular operation) you only need `KEY_READ `? 3) Don't `inline` everything just for the sake of having everything in a `.h` file. Do it the "old (&& good) fashioned way": place the definitions in a `.h(pp)` file and the implementation in a `.c(pp)` file.

Comment: it should also include KEY_QUERY_VALUE  and in order to avoid any other issues I have also tested with KEY_ALL_ACCESS.

Comment: `KEY_READ` does include it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you simplify the code so it doesn't use a custom class? Just show the API calls. It looks like the interesting one is `RegQueryInfoKey`. Note also that there is a 64-bit registry and a 32-bit registry. What program are you using to determine that the registry key has 1725 values?

Comment: Do the 64/32 bit registry entries overlap? That'w what Wow6432Node should do.

Comment: I wrote in the question, the app is 64-bit, and of course I am looking at the normal 64-bit location with regedit.

Comment: Anyway both locations 64-bit and Wow6432Node have the same SharedDLLs number. So this is sure not an issue.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have exported the registry key with regedit, then stripped the text to be one entry on each line and then notepad++ tells me the number of lines.

Comment: Your code sample includes methods that you never call (and are therefore irrelevant), and you omitted the `Open` method. I again recommend that you reduce the problem by removing the class entirely and just show the API calls. Also, use the debugger to see what values are returned by the APIs.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have not omitted the Open! the class is inherited from CRegKey if you look at the public declarator. It uses the standard CRegKey Open. The APIs return the same wrong value I have put a brakepoint on the CRegKeyEx::QueryInfo -> ::RegQueryInfoKey... and the incorrect value comes from there.

Comment: Okay, so all the `CRegKeyOpen` stuff is a red herring and is not relevant to the problem. The problem is that `RegQueryInfoKey` is not returning the values you expect.